# What is the nginx version of these .htaccess rules?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

How should I rewrite this htaccess rules to nginx kind of rules:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?puppy/index.php$ 
RewriteRule . /puppy/index.php

Answer (score 3):

In nginx, you won't use a rewrite for this at all. You would use [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/r/try_files) instead. For example:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /puppy/index.php;
```

Or, more likely, `try_files` along with a named `location` to handle PHP scripts.

This isn't something that should be done in isolation; it is an integral part of the entire `server` block and you should not consider it separately.